# Configured 404 error page not shown in JAX-RS Application

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have the following problem: I've created a Java web application. Additionally, I made some REST endpoints. In the web.xml I defined a redirect for the 404 error with the use of the  tags. It works properly for all addresses except for the non-existing REST endpoints. I implemented the RestApplication class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

and one endpoint, myView:

```
@Path("/myView")
public class MyView {

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public Response myViewPage() {
        //some code goes here...
    }
}
```

and now, when I try to enter the non-existing endpoint, let's say "aaa", i.e. I enter the address: http://localhost:8080/mysite/rest/aaa, I get 404 error, but the redirect doesn't work. For the non-REST addresses, e.g.: http://localhost:8080/mysite/somesitethatdoesnotexist, redirect works properly. My web.xml looks as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
                            version="3.1">
                            
    <context-param>
       <param-name>resteasy.document.expand.entity.references</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restricted methods</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

I also tried to use the ExceptionMapper, i.e. I implemented the EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper class:

```
@Provider
public class EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException ex) {
      // some code for redirect
    }
}
```

and added it to the RestApplication class:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(EntityNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. However, it worked when I removed the:

```html
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

from web.xml. But, unfortunately, the redirect of course didn't work for the non-REST addresses.

Can anyone help me with this issue and suggest the solution that would allow me to provide redirect in case of 404 error for both REST and non-REST addresses? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Following the remark of @andih, for the REST service, I want to return a configured 404 error page in the case that a resource is not available.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you expect. Http Status Code 404 means "Not Found". There is no redirect. Whom do you want to redirect? A standard http / rest client will not follow redirects when he gets a 404 Status Code. If you want to redirect the clients you'll have to use http status codes 3xx. Take care you may have to configure your clients to automatically follow redirects.

Comment: It's true that standard 404 doesn't do the redirect, therefore I added <error-page> tags to the web.xml, which provide that when client gets 404, he will be redirected to the 404.xhtml. But it doesn't work if he gets 404 from REST... And that's my problem.

Comment: Your application is both `web.xml` as well as  annotations based. You want that your annotations based part - which you call rest addresses - to return your configured 404 error page in the case that a resource is not available, which has nothing to do with redirects. Is that correct? Can you than please reformulate your question / problem description this way? Does your Annotation (REST) part work for existing resources?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So I'm going to edit my question. And yes, Annotation (REST) work properly for existing resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty sure why your rest resources are found at all but for complex deployments with `web.xml` and Annotations to work you'll have to do a little bit more.

Your `RestApplication` class must extend `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` to define the components of a RESTful Web service application deployment. For more details about `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`, see the Javadoc at http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html

Within your `Application` subclass you have to  override either the `getClasses()` or the `getSingletons()` methods, as required, to return the list of RESTful Web service resources.

For Example

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(HelloResource.class);
        return s;
    }

}
```

With the Hello REST resource.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

In your `web.xml` you'll have to define your REST Application.
You can configure more than one if you need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <!-- The servlet name is the full qualified name of your rest application it must be a subclass of java.ws.rs.Application --> 
        <servlet-name>org.example.restexample.RestApplication</servlet-name>
        <!--servlet-class is not needed -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <!-- As init parameter pass the full qualified name of the java.ws.rs.Application subclass --> 
            <param-value>org.example.restexample.RestApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- other servlet definitions --> 
    

    <--servlet mapping --> 

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/NotFound.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

You may specify a servlet mapping for your JaxRS Application(s). If you do so the `<servlet-mapping>` will take precedence.

The example above returns the configured 404 error page if a resource like
".../rest/foo" is requested where as ".../rest/hello" returns "Hello".

The example above was tested with jersey 2.26-b03 and tomcat 8.5.15.